# Razor templates: Cannot find compilation library location for package

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I ran into this error with .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Core 2.1, while using [RazorLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorLight/) coupled with cshtml Razor template files for [FluentEmail](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentEmail.Razor/), in an ASP.NET Core app:

> "Cannot find compilation library location for package *XYZ*"

Where *XYZ* seemed to change depending on what version of .NET Core I had deployed.

The error did not present itself in my dev environment, but reared its head after deployment, when hitting any API endpoint that required FluentEmail to use the Razor template files to generate the email body.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Publish-time compilation of Razor files is enabled by default. In my case, I did not need this feature, because my Razor templates were being compiled by FluentEmail at runtime. By adding `<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>` to the app's csproj file, publish-time compilation was disabled, and the error resolved.

**Example csproj entry**:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: You saved my day:) Had the same issue. Thx for the solution.

Comment: For some reason this solution didn't help me. I have described details here: https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight/issues/203. Any help\ideas are really appreciated.