# System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package MessagePack?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Created asp.net core project it's running in locally but I tried to deploy the application in IIS server but I got this exception System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package MessagePack.

Can you please help me on this issue.
THanks
Ram

Comment: Also got another exception System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore'.can you please any help me on this .

Comment: I fixed this issue based on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269559/razor-templates-cannot-find-compilation-library-location-for-package?rq=1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after hours i found this solution.
Go to csproj and add the following code.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I changed but it's not working same error comming.below my csproj

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.2.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>


</Project>

Comment: I fixed this issue based on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269559/razor-templates-cannot-find-compilation-library-location-for-package?rq=1